# appcompat-v7:28.0.0-beta01 Broke after update

Tags: android-studio, android-appcompat

I am beginner in Android studio and installed it yesterday. Then I created a empty project that worked just fine. Today I had to update and now I am fighting with that error message:

[image]

As you can see I already included the Examples. Any ideas how I can fix that?
Here the full app.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "at.sumser.fateandlove"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-beta01'

    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0-beta01'

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
}
```

Funny, that it tells me to add 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0' when the SDK is 28? Any ideas?

**UPDATE**
Here is also the build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.41'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Now the 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0' does also tell me about a problem:
[image]

Question: Does Google not test their releases? Or is the autoresolver in Android Studio just broken? I lost now nearly 3 hours to find a fix for this issue...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just had the same issue when updating to AppCompat version 28.

First I recommend to use the latest version which is `28.0.0-rc01` instead of `28.0.0-beta01`.

If you then still get the warning that all libraries must use the exact same version specification, you can force to use the latest version for the corresponding library.

You can do so by adding a resolution strategy to your apps `build.gradle` file within `android { }` like this:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-rc01'
        force 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0-rc01'
        force 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0-rc01'
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to add the 'configuration.all' resolution too and to change the Kotlin jre to the jdk: `implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"`

Finally it worked. Thank you very very much, :)
This is really a challenge for beginners...

Comment: I was struggling adding the excludes. This worked for me. Thank you!